# MobX not updating React Component when computed array is changed

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a list of todos in store which is not sorted. A computed value is added to store that returns sorted todos. The React Component is using `sortedTodos` to display the list. Whenever the todos list changes, the component is not re-rendered, if I use `todos` directly it works.

```js
export class TodoStore {
  @observable todos: Todo[] = [
    { description: "testing", createdAt: new Date(), isCompleted: false },
  ];

  @computed get sortedTodos(): Todo[] {
    const sortedTodos = this.todos.sort(
      (a, b) => a.createdAt.getTime() - b.createdAt.getTime()
    );
    return sortedTodos;
  }

  @action addTodo = (description: string) => {
    this.todos.push({
      description,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      isCompleted: false,
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mobx, but I do know react does shallow reference equality checks of state/props to determine if a component should rerender. Arrays are sorted in place, so the array reference doesn't change. If `sortedTodos` returns a *new* array it may work.

Comment: Your mobx code is correct. Can you post component code or make a reproduction on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem.

Instead of directly assigning an array, I used `observable.array` and it works.

```
export class TodoStore {
  @observable todos: Todo[] = observable.array();

  ...
}
```

Not completely sure why so but it works. I think the reason is that by using a regular array, the objects inside are not observables by default, when using `observable.array` the objects of array themselves are observables.

Comment: You can then you remove  `@observable` decorator.

Comment: @IvanV. Is there a decorator that would take care of this behaviour i.e. it could make the children of array observables as well.

Comment: It is strange that the `@decorator` is not working in the first place.
Also  `observable` and `observable.array` are `deep` by default, meaning that anything added to the array will also be made observable.
I still think that you have an error in the way how you are using the observables in react components. 
The original code you posted works as expected.